# Renaming all occurances of an HTML class name inside a table with SQL

Tags: mysql, query, regex, replace

In a MYSQL database of a CMS all occurances of a specific HTML class name should be pre-fixed.
Let's say the table of interest is `table_article` and the HTML code inside this table is like this:

```
<div>
  <p class="myclass someotherclass1 someotherclass2">Some text.</p>
  <p class="someotherclass1 myclass someotherclass2">Some more text that contains the class name not as class, but as text: myclass</p>
</div>
```

So the SQL statement should rename the class name "myclass" to "prefix-myclass" **wherever it may occur as an HTML class name**, but without renaming the occurences of the string when it's not a class name:

```
<div>
  <p class="prefix-myclass someotherclass1 someotherclass2">Some text.</p>
  <p class="someotherclass1 prefix-myclass someotherclass2">Some more text that contains the class name not as class, but as text: myclass</p>
</div>
```

What's the SQL statement for such an operation?

EDIT: the HTML classes may occur not only in

tags, they can occur in every possible HTML tag.

Comment: In other words, there is a DB table column contains the entire snippet of HTML code?

Comment: Yes, it's like that.

Comment: Some tasks are better done in application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT html,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(html, '(<p .*class.*"| )myclass(.*[^p]>)', '$1prefix-myclass$2')
FROM test
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e675fc3259589daa5231996b506553a4

Comment: Thanks, the statement works great, but it is not generic enough: the classes can occur not only in <p> tags but also in any other HTML tag like. What has to be changed in your code to work in every tag?